# Error: IndexOutOfBoundsException while calculation sum of array

Tags: kotlin, exception, compiler-errors

I'm trying to calculate sum of the array.

```
fun main (args: Array<String>) {
   var myArray = arrayOf(66, 23, 5, 46, 76, 56, 3, 277, 6, 9494, 574, 34, 23, 6467, 13, 64, 75, 634, 234, 2314)
   println("The sum of the array is: ${getSumArray(myArray)}")
}
   fun getSumArray(myArray: Array<Int>): Int {
      var total = 0
      var index = 0
      for (number in myArray) {
         do {
            total = total + myArray[index]
            index++
         } while (index < myArray.size)
      }
      return total
   }
```

IDE prints an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 20 out of bounds for length 20  at
> ExercisesKt.getSumArray(Exercises.kt:19)  at
> ExercisesKt.main(Exercises.kt:12)

In https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html I found:

> public class IndexOutOfBoundsException extends RuntimeException Thrown
> to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a
> string, or to a vector) is out of range.

How I understand it means that `index` is out of range of `myArray.size`. Why is that?

Comment: Add `println(number)` after `for (number in myArray) {` and comment out your `do while` block. Then observe your logs... You will realize that its the only loop you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the array twice, once using the `for` loop and inner `do-while` loop. As the `index` is defined outside both the loops, it gets assigned to `myArray.size`. trying to access array element with index larger than size-1 will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**How to debug**

For beginners, start adding `print` statements within the code to see what the value is at particular moment. If you are using any IDE like Intellij, start using breakpoint to check the values are runtime

Here are few alternatives to fix the issue.

Use just the for loop

```
fun getSumArray(myArray: Array<Int>): Int {
  var total = 0
  for (number in myArray) {
    total += number
  }
  return total
}
```

or use the while loop

```
fun getSumArray(myArray: Array<Int>): Int {
  var total = 0
  var index = 0
    do {
      total = total + myArray[index]
      index++
    } while (index < myArray.size)
  return total
}
```

Or use Kotlin's existing function to get the sum

```
fun getSumArray(myArray: Array<Int>): Int {
  return myArray.sum()
}
```

Some additional (unnecessary) options

```
fun getSumArray(myArray: Array<Int>): Int {
  var total = 0
  myArray.forEach {
    total+=it
  }
  return total
}
```

.

```
fun getSumArray(myArray: Array<Int>): Int {
  return myArray.reduce { acc, n -> acc + n }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of `for (number in myArray)` loop? It is the source of this error. After first iteration of this loop `index` variable is equal to `myArray.size`. On the next iteration you get this exception because in do-while loops the body executes first and then condition is checked.

By the way, there is a nice [sum](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) method defined for arrays in kotlin.